# "Node Recommendation" Module alternatives

Tags: 7, nodes

I what hoping to use the Node Recommendation module for drupal 6, but after testing it for a while I have come to realize that this particular module has to many issues.

http://drupal.org/project/noderecommendation

The idea of the module is excellent! give node recommendations based on related taxonomy terms and content types.

Are there any alternatives that are under active development and are stable enough that do something similar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two excellent modules, both compatible with Drupal versions 6 *and* 7:

1. If you want to display similar nodes calculated by the actual node content, try [Similar entries](http://drupal.org/project/similar)
2. If you want to display similar nodes calculated by some sort of taxonomy setup, try [Similar By Terms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms)

There's also [Relevant Content](http://drupal.org/project/relevant_content), a module which allows you to configure the recommended nodes based on many different things, with different block configurations and stuff for dealing with CCK. I haven't used it, but I've heard it's quite good.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I think we will go with Relevant Content as it seems to fit our needs better than Similar entries or Similar By Terms. It was also super easy to get up and running.

Comment: Happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

May be [relatedcontent](http://drupal.org/project/relatedcontent). . But I prefer [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) for this as more flexible tools.